# How to compare strings of two files?

Tags: c, arrays, string, compare

I am a new c-language programmer.

I have got two files.
One consists of lines like:

> 84:1b:5e:a8:bf:7f
>
> 00:8e:f2:c0:13:cc

Another consists of lines like:

> 00-22-39
>
> 8C-FD-F0

My question is how can I using C language compare first half of line in the first file with a line in the second file?
Like: is **84:1b:5e** equals to **8C-FD-F0**?
I know the way to create an arrays to store those lines for the further comparison. But do I really need to create arrays?

P.S: comparison is **case-insensitive**

Comment: After Loading both files using FILE *fp = fopen("C:\\somefile.txt", "r"); and FILE *fp2 = fopen(C:\\someotherfile.txt", "r"); Then use fgets() on each file.  Then You can use strstr(,) to compare the lines.  don't forget to free the fp's when you are done.

Comment: I suspect code will be required. And in writing it, a MAC parser and OUI parser will likely be warranted, with results in thankfully-fixed structures or subarrays. Properly done (the OUIs should be in a sorted array of structures including the vendor name), this could be quite efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't been very clear about what rules constitute a match. But if you want to compare the byte values, then you need to parse each line, converting it to those byte values.

You could use variations of `strtok()` to get the values from each line. However, a variation of `sscanf()` might be easier. Once you have the binary values from each file, then you can compare them.

Comment: Actually my first file consists of MAC addresses and my second file consists of OUIs and vendor names. So I am going to compare first 3 bytes of MAC address and if they are equal to OUI then I print the relevant vendor name.

Answer (score 0):

Read the second file completely and store the contents in a sorted array. Then for each line read from the first file, binary search the sorted array to locate the match.

Implementation is below. It compiles with gcc.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>

int cmp(const void * s1, const void * s2)
{
    return strcasecmp(*(char **)s1, *(char **)s2);
}

int cmp_half(const char * s1, const char * s2)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        int res = strncasecmp((char *)s1+i*3, (char *)s2+i*3, 2);
        if (res != 0) return res;
    }

    return 0;
}

char * line[1024];
int n = 0;

int search(const char * s)
{
    int first, last, middle;
    first = 0;
    last = n - 1;
    middle = (first+last)/2;

    while( first <= last )
    {
        int res = cmp_half(s, line[middle]);
        if (res == 0) return middle;
        if (res > 0)
            first = middle + 1;    
        else
            last = middle - 1;

        middle = (first + last)/2;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main()
{
    FILE * f1, * f2;
    char * s;
    char buf[1024*1024], text[1024];

    f1 = fopen("file1.txt", "rt");
    f2 = fopen("file2.txt", "rt");

    s = buf;
    while (fgets(s, 1024, f2) != NULL)
    {
        line[n] = s;
        s = s+strlen(s)+1;
        n++;
    }

    qsort(line, n, sizeof(char *), cmp);

    while (fgets(text, 1024, f1) != NULL)
    {
    text[strlen(text)-1] = 0;
        int idx = search(text);
        if (idx >= 0)
        {
            printf("%s matched %s\n", text, line[idx]);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s not matched\n", text);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```